# MonoDB Fails to Connect with Heroku im using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, heroku, pymongo

2021-04-18T19:25:28.390166+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in on_ready

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392098+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392152+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392172+00:00 app[worker.1]: await coro(*args, **kwargs)

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392173+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/bot.py", line 102, in on_ready

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392173+00:00 app[worker.1]: for document in await bot.config.get_all():

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392174+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/utils/mongo.py", line 34, in get_all

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392175+00:00 app[worker.1]: return await self.db.find(filter, *args, **kwargs).to_list(None)

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392181+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/motor/core.py", line 1373, in _to_list

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392182+00:00 app[worker.1]: result = get_more_result.result()

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392182+00:00 app[worker.1]: File
"/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 52, in run

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392183+00:00 app[worker.1]: result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392183+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1100, in _refresh

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392184+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392184+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1816, in _ensure_session

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392184+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392185+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1766, in __start_session

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392185+00:00 app[worker.1]: server_session = self._get_server_session()
2021-04-18T19:25:28.392186+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-
packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1802, in _get_server_session

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392187+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self._topology.get_server_session()

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392187+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 490, in get_server_session

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392187+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._select_servers_loop(

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392191+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 215, in _select_servers_loop

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392191+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(

2021-04-18T19:25:28.392218+00:00 app[worker.1]: pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 607c8787b4a426e578b8b9d0, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('02-shard-00-00.kbi7i.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('02-shard-00-01.kbi7i.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('02-shard-00-02.kbi7i.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('connection closed')>]>

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem on mongo DB I had only whitelisted my house ip but if you allow access to Heroku or whosever ip its being hosted off it fixes it (or set it to everyone's ip more of a security risk though)